# Why I am not able to type in html react input box?

Tags: reactjs

Why I am not able to type in react app input box?
I can not type in input box if I have onChange method, name and value in it. What am I doing wrong? Please check the following link for code

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-bell-n72jg?file=/src/App.js)

```
import "./styles.css";
import React  from 'react';
class App extends React.Component {
  

  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      username:'',
      name:'',
      message:'',
      password:''
    }
  }
handleChange = (e) => {
this.setState = ({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
}
handleSubmit = (e) =>{
e.preventDefault()
console.log(this.state);
}
  render() {
    const { username, name, message, password } = this.state
      return (
          <div>
            <h2> contact</h2>
            <form onSubmit= {this.handleSubmit}>
              <div>
                Username: 
                <input 
                className="inputBox pMID" 
                type="text" 
                // name="username"
                // value={ username } 
                // onChange= { this.handleChange} 
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                Name:
                <input 
                className="inputBox" 
                type="text" 
                name="name"
                value= { name } 
                onChange= { this.handleChange} 
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                Message:
                <input 
                className="inputBox" 
                type="text" 
                name="message"
                value= { message } 
                onChange= { this.handleChange} 
                />
              </div>
              <button className="submitBtn tab-btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
            {/* <input className="inputBox" 
                type="password" 
                name="password"
                value= { password } 
                onChange= { this.handleChange}
                /> */}
          </div>
      );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Voting to close as typo: `this.setState = ({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });` should be `this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });`.

Comment: `this.setState` is a function. You need to call it, not assign a value. See the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass an object(acc to your code, you can also pass a callback function that returns an object that will get assign state) to assign the value in `this.setState`. You are assigning the object to `this.setState`. [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-rhodes-8dsk5?file=/src/App.js)

You need to change calling the `` from

```
this.setState = ({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
```

to

```
this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
```